# Expect undefined to be number: How to convert the undefined to number?

Tags: javascript, undefined

I've been trying to figure it out for the past 3 days but was unable to come up with a solution after running several tests in Jasmine. How do I fix it so that I can pass one of the tests "Expect undefined to be a number" whereas the duration of the movies should be a number?

I know that undefined only happens if the object property doesn't exist or if a declared variable isn't assigned a value yet.

Here's what I did with the code

```
let movies = [
  {
    title: 'The Shawshank Redemption',
    year: '1994',
    director: 'Frank Darabont',
    duration: '2h 22min',
    genre: ['Crime', 'Drama'],
    rate: '9.3'
  },
  {
    title: 'The Godfather',
    year: '1972',
    director: 'Francis Ford Coppola',
    duration: '2h 55min',
    genre: ['Crime', 'Drama'],
    rate: '9.2'
  },
  {
    title: 'The Godfather: Part II',
    year: '1974',
    director: 'Francis Ford Coppola',
    duration: '3h 22min',
    genre: ['Crime', 'Drama'],
    rate: '9.0'
  }
]

function turnHoursToMinutes(minutesArr) {
  let durationArr = minutesArr.map(currentItem => {
    let stringtime = currentItem.duration;
    if (typeof stringtime === "string" && stringtime !== null && stringtime !== "" && stringtime !== undefined) {
    let strnumbers = stringtime.match(/\d+/g);
    let numbers = strnumbers.map(Number);
    let minutes = 0;
    if (stringtime.includes("h") && stringtime.includes("min")) {
      minutes = (numbers[0] * 60) + numbers[1];
    } else if (stringtime.includes("h")) {
      minutes = numbers[0] * 60;
    } else if (stringtime.includes("min")) {
      minutes = numbers[0];
    } 
    currentItem.duration = minutes;
    return {...currentItem};
    } else if (typeof stringtime === "number") {
      return currentItem.duration;
    } else if (typeof stringtime === "undefined") {
      return currentItem.duration = 0;
    }
  });

  return durationArr;

}
console.log(turnHoursToMinutes(movies));
```

As you can see, I tried to add the object property as well the value like this `currentItem.duration = 0`. I thought I could cover my bases if I wrote this code. Please let me know what's wrong with my code and how to fit it.

Comment: `return currentItem.duration = 0;` but `=` is assignment, not comparison. If that's intentional, best to put `return` on a separate line. But you probably shouldn't be using `.map` at all, if you're trying to mutate the existing array

Comment: Can you store the duration in minutes and convert to hours & minutes where you need to?

Answer (score 0):

`turnHoursToMinutes` does not correctly handle the case where the value of `duration` is already a `Number` or is `undefined`. See this annotated version of your function

```
function turnHoursToMinutes(minutesArr) {
  // >>> consider just returning the mapped Array
  return minutesArr.map(currentItem => {
    let stringtime = currentItem.duration;
    if (typeof stringtime === "string" &&
      stringtime !== null &&
      stringtime !== "" && stringtime !== undefined) {
      let strnumbers = stringtime.match(/\d+/g);
      let numbers = strnumbers.map(Number);
      let minutes = 0;
      if (stringtime.includes("h") && stringtime.includes("min")) {
        minutes = (numbers[0] * 60) + numbers[1];
      } else if (stringtime.includes("h")) {
        minutes = numbers[0] * 60;
      } else if (stringtime.includes("min")) {
        minutes = numbers[0];
      }
      currentItem.duration = minutes;

      // >>> no need for the spread and no need to return currentItem here
      // return {...currentItem};
    }

    // >>> no need for this case, because it's already a number
    // and that was what you wanted in the first place
    //!else if (typeof stringtime === "number") {

    // >>> this is why your test fails. You are still in the 'map' lambda
    // and should return currentItem, not the propery
    //!  return currentItem.duration;
    //!}
    //!else if (typeof stringtime === "undefined") {

    // >>> same: should've returned currentItem
    //!  return currentItem.duration = 0;
    //!}
    // >>> the above can be simplified to
    currentItem.duration = currentItem.duration || 0;
    // >>> now you've covered all, so return currentItem
    return currentItem;
  });
}
```

Anyway, I took the liberty to simplify your code. This refactoring extracts the code to determine the numeric value (in minutes) of `duration`, which in turn can be used in a (re)mapping of the movies object.

```js
const calcMinutesFromDurationString = str =>
  str ? String(str).split(" ")
          .reduce( (acc, val) => 
            acc + ( val.endsWith("h") ?  60 * parseInt(val)  : parseInt(val)), 0) 
      : 0;
    
const mapMoviesWithDurationInMinutes = item => 
  ( { ...item, duration: calcMinutesFromDurationString(item.duration) || 0 } );

console.log(getMovies().map(mapMoviesWithDurationInMinutes));

// ----------------
function getMovies() {
  return [
    {
      title: 'The Shawshank Redemption',
      year: '1994',
      director: 'Frank Darabont',
      duration: '2h 22min',
      genre: ['Crime', 'Drama'],
      rate: '9.3'
    },
    {
      title: 'The Godfather',
      year: '1972',
      director: 'Francis Ford Coppola',
      duration: '2h 55min',
      genre: ['Crime', 'Drama'],
      rate: '9.2'
    },
    {
      title: 'The Godfather: Part II',
      year: '1974',
      director: 'Francis Ford Coppola',
      duration: '3h 22min',
      genre: ['Crime', 'Drama'],
      rate: '9.0'
    },
    // added 1 without 'duration' 
    // actually the movie lasts 15 minutes :P
    {
      title: 'Capital Execution',
      year: '1903',
      director: 'Peter Elfelt',
      genre: ['Drama'],
      rate: 'n/a'
    },
    // added 1 with 'duration' = 'unknown' string
    {
      title: 'The Lamb',
      year: '1915',
      director: 'W. Christy Cabanne',
      genre: ['Comedy', 'Western'],
      rate: 'n/a',
      duration: 'unknown'
    },
    // added 1 with 'duration' = 71 (minutes)
    {
      title: 'Frankenstein',
      year: '1931',
      director: 'Robert Florey',
      genre: ['Drama', 'Horror'],
      rate: 'n/a',
      duration: 71
    },
  ];
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important
}
```

What's more: now you can test the conversion indepently

```js
const calcMinutesFromDurationString = str =>
  str ? String(str).split(" ")
  .reduce((acc, val) =>
    acc + (val.endsWith("h") ? 60 * parseInt(val) : parseInt(val)), 0) || 0 :
  0;
  
console.log(`Converted values\n  calcMinutesFromDurationString("5h 0min") => ${
  calcMinutesFromDurationString("5h 0min")}\n  calcMinutesFromDurationString("") => ${
  calcMinutesFromDurationString("")}\n  calcMinutesFromDurationString("unknown") => ${
  calcMinutesFromDurationString("unknown")}\n  calcMinutesFromDurationString(65) => ${
  calcMinutesFromDurationString(65)}\n  calcMinutesFromDurationString("65min") => ${
  calcMinutesFromDurationString("65min")}\n  calcMinutesFromDurationString("1h") => ${
  calcMinutesFromDurationString("1h")}\n  calcMinutesFromDurationString() =>  ${
  calcMinutesFromDurationString()}\n  calcMinutesFromDurationString(null) => ${
  calcMinutesFromDurationString(null)}\n  calcMinutesFromDurationString("120") => ${
  calcMinutesFromDurationString("120")}`);
  
const isNumber = val => typeof val === "number" ? "yes" : "nope";
  
console.log(`Are we talking numbers here?
  calcMinutesFromDurationString("5h 0min") => ${
  isNumber(calcMinutesFromDurationString("5h 0min"))}
  calcMinutesFromDurationString("") => ${
  isNumber(calcMinutesFromDurationString(""))}
  calcMinutesFromDurationString("unknown") => ${
  isNumber(calcMinutesFromDurationString("unknown"))}
  calcMinutesFromDurationString(65) => ${
  isNumber(calcMinutesFromDurationString(65))}
  calcMinutesFromDurationString("65min") => ${
  isNumber(calcMinutesFromDurationString("65min"))}
  calcMinutesFromDurationString("1h") => ${
  isNumber(calcMinutesFromDurationString("1h"))}
  calcMinutesFromDurationString() =>  ${
  isNumber(calcMinutesFromDurationString())}
  calcMinutesFromDurationString(null) => ${
  isNumber(calcMinutesFromDurationString(null))}
  calcMinutesFromDurationString("120") => ${
  isNumber(calcMinutesFromDurationString("120"))}`);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important
}
```

Comment: `  it("The duration of the movie should be a number", function() {
    expect(typeof turnHoursToMinutes(movies)[0].duration).toBe("number");
  });` This is what my code was testing against in Jasmine. All I did was to convert a string into a number, converting hours/minutes into minutes.

Comment: @KristinaBressler See the revised answer

Answer (score 0):

In your turnHoursToMinutes function, it handles 3 conditions:

1. currentItem.duration is a string, in this case it converts currentItem.duration to a number and return a copy of currentItem.
2. currentItem.duration is a number, in this case the function just returns the value of currentItem.duration
3. currentItem.duration is undefined, in this case the function sets currentItem.duration to 0 and returns 0

Did you notice that in last two cases the function doesn't return the whole object, instead it returns a single number?

A simple fix is to change the returns in last two cases to return currentItem after setting duration to the appropriate value if needed.

Comment: My homework was to convert the string into numbers, transforming hours/minutes into minutes. I assumed that the last test in Jasmine was testing in case if there's no duration in the object properties or if the duration wasn't assigned a value yet. Here is the code Jasmine was testing my code in `it("The duration of the movie should be a number", function() {
    expect(typeof turnHoursToMinutes(movies)[0].duration).toBe("number");
  });`

Comment: In the test it expects turnHoursToMinutes to return an array of the movies, not just array of durations. So just change `return currentItem.duration = 0;` to `currentItem.duration = 0; return currentItem;`